# Positioning text by axis fraction

Tags: python, text, matplotlib

Is there a way to position text in a figure by the fraction of the axis? I want the text in the same position for all my plots regardless of their differing ranges in x and y. This functionality is in ax.annotate() but I need to put in the extra 'xy' argument which makes my code harder to read.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(np.arange(10),12*np.arange(10)) 
ax.annotate('Correct Position', xy=(0, 0), xytext=(0.4, 0.7), textcoords='axes fraction')
ax.text(0.4, 0.7, 'Incorrect Position')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `transform` keyword:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(np.arange(10),12*np.arange(10)) 
ax.text(0.4, 0.7, 'Correct Position', transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.show()
```